# Beyond the LP relaxation of binary least squares

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a binary quadratic program with a convex objective function, of the form,

\begin{align}
\text{minimize}\;\;& x^tAx+b^tx\\
\text{subject to}\;\;& x_i\in\{0,1\}
\end{align}

where $A$ is positive semidefinite.

I've played around a bit with semidefinite relaxations of this problem, but after some empirical testing, they appear to be (at best) equivalent to the standard LP relaxation.

The ability to reformulate the original problem as,

\begin{align}
\text{minimize}\;\;& x^tAx+b^tx\\
\text{subject to}\;\;& x^t(x-{\bf 1})=0\\
& 0\leq x_i\leq1
\end{align}

makes a more sophisticated relaxation seem tantalizingly possible.

Does there exist a canonical relaxation of this problem which is superior to the standard LP relaxation?

Comment: The commonly used SDP relaxation can be much stronger than the commonly used LP relaxation of QUBO, so the premise of your question is false.  You might improve the question by providing more context.

Comment: @BrianBorchers My attempts at SDP relaxations did not produce a better optimum in practice, but I have no proof that they are not sometimes of better quality, and I am no authority on the subject. Could you point me to a reference detailing the commonly used SDP relaxation for QUBO?

Comment: Poljak, Svatopluk, Franz Rendl, and Henry Wolkowicz. "A recipe for semidefinite relaxation for (0, 1)-quadratic programming: In memory of Svata Poljak." Journal of Global Optimization 7, no. 1 (1995): 51-73.